# What does 見切り最少の動作で mean in this context ? (describing a girl dodging an attack from a robot)

Tags: meaning, japanese-to-english, video-games

Much thanks if anyone can help me understand the correct meaning

> 名状しがたい唸りを発して長い右腕をしならせ、鞭のように放つ。
>
> Girl「ハッ！」
>
> それを完全に**見切り最少の動作で**かわすと、美麗な戦姫が軽やかに舞い上がる。

(my guess is "After she had completely dodged that attack effortlessly with minimum movement, the battle princess soaring up in to the air easily like a bird" but i'm not sure, because of the 見切り最少の動作 part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`完全に見切り` and `最小の動作で` are separated. The sentence can be `それを完全に見切り、最小の動作でかわすと、...`.

`見切り` means "seeing through", so the translation will be something like "After she had completely seen through the attack and dodged it effortlessly with minimum movement".

Answer (score 0):

There is also another explanation from a Japanese guy. I will post it here so anyone in the future who has the same problem as me can read it as a reference

> 英語だと正確に伝える自信がないので日本語で。
>
> ロボットの腕に当たらなければダメージを負いませんよね。当たらないという点では、1mかわしても1cmかわしても同じく当たらないわけです。腕の軌道を正確に把握できさえすれば、1mmでかわしたっていいわけです。この「正確に把握する」ことを「見切る」といいます。